# import binance api data into google sheet

Tags: api, google-apps-script, google-sheets, binance, google-code

I'm just a newbie trying to import raw binance api data into a google sheet. I tried using Mixed Analytics API Connector but the result is usually "completed with errors". And the support team suggestions didn't help at all with the end result still the same and so the data is still the same from its previous data that was a week old already.
You could see the raw binance api data on the link below.

https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/24hr

And so I think it, the way only to tackle this problem would be to code it as a google script.
I would greatly appreciate any help I can get.
Any sample code gs code would be very helpful.
Thank you very much...

Comment: Unfortunately, from your question, I cannot image the output you expect. I apologize for my poor English skill. In order to correctly understand about your question, can you provide the sample output situation as an image?

Comment: hi @Tanaike! thanks for looking into this problem I'm having.  what I want is for all the data resulting from the link mentioned above to be displayed on a google sheet. Hope this will give you some clarification. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution. Put a triger if needed on the function horodatage (i.e. each day)

```
// Mike Steelson

let resultat = [];

// mettre déclencheur horaire sur cette fonction
// define a trigger here
function horodatage(){
  var f = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Data')
  f.getRange('A1').setValue(!f.getRange('A1').getValue())
  f.getRange('B1').setValue(new Date())
}

function getDataJSON(url,xpath){
  try{
    if (url.match(/http(s)?:\/\/?/g)){var data = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText())}
    else{var data = JSON.parse(url)}
    var json = eval('data')
    if (typeof xpath == 'object'){var liste = xpath.join().split(",")} else {var liste = xpath.split("|")}
    if (json.length){json.forEach(function(elem){getData(elem,liste)})} else {getData(json,liste)}
    return resultat
  }
  catch(e) {
    return ('Pas de résultat - vérifier l\'url et les paramètres !');
  }
}
function getData(elem,liste){
  var prov=[]
  liste.forEach(function(chemin){
    var t=chemin.split('/');
    var obj=elem;
    for (var i=1;i<t.length;i++){obj=obj.item(t[i])}
    if(typeof obj=='object'){prov.push('['+obj+']')}else{prov.push(obj)}
  })
  resultat.push(prov)
}
Object.prototype.item=function(i){return this[i]};
```

you can take a copy of this spreadsheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DN0Gfim0LC098zVgrUpt2crPWUn4pWfZnCpuuL1ZiMs/copy

Comment: Hi @Mike Steelson!  Thank you for giving some of your time to tackle one of my current problem. And thanks for the sample code and a copy of your google sheet. 

As I tried to used your sample google sheet, there are many data that has not been passed onto the sheet coming from the data from the link : 
https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/24hr

Comment: What I was trying to do was to fetch all the raw data from the above link and paste it into one of my google sheet.

Comment: I recently used an add-ons from Mixed Analytics which is the API Connector, which result to the following data  shown on the link below

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1G7rB22kuAjWoJnad4cxeHNvXoP_l7yjuL6np2CiZkSc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: All of the raw binance api data was exported to that sheet simply just by clicking the menu button under API Connector, "Refresh All Request".

Comment: But recently it constantly not updating the data whenever I click on the same menu button. And so this is the last recently updated sheet which is outdated already.

Comment: Hope this give some clarification on what I'm trying to do..   Thanks

Comment: Raquel, all you need is inside 'data' sheet. 'Porfolio' sheet is just an extract for some pairs, you can forget it (and erase). I put a checkbox in A1 so that the formula in A3 will be activated.

Comment: All you need is that https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tGH9BYhvHNc-DmtccevcLCx7wQp0gKvt0kJaiPvlAgE/edit?usp=sharing ?

Answer (score 0):

i cannot comment but here could be a solution, instead of  api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/24hr write api1.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/24hr
I have added 1 to api. in a video I saw it works for him.... but for me didnt work.
let me know if it was useful
thanks